# How to build a callback method?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to build a simple class in Javascript which allows user to check if user is Typing in an input field.

My current code looks something like this :

```
var CheckTyping = function(){
            return {
                typingTimer: null,
                doneTypingInterval: 2000,
                doneTyping : false,
                done : function(callback){
                    return callback();
                },
                start: function(){
                    clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
                        this.typingTimer = setTimeout(this.done, this.doneTypingInterval);
                },
                end: function(){
                    clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
                }
            }
        }();
```

**HTML:**

```
<input onkeyup='CheckTyping.start()' onkeydown='CheckTyping.end()'>
```

I want my API to look something like this:
**JS**

```
    CheckTyping.done(function(){
        // this is my callback function which should work only when user is done typing.
        // do something         
    });
```

Currently the callback function is getting executed automatically. I want the funtion to run only when it is called by setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
return (function() {
    var _done = null;
    return {
        typingTimer: null,
        doneTypingInterval: 2000,
        doneTyping : false,
        done : function(callback){
            _done = callback;
        },
        start: function(){
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
                this.typingTimer = setTimeout(_done, this.doneTypingInterval);
        },
        end: function(){
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
        }
    };
}())
```

or other ways to save the callback. Then use the saved function in your timeout. You might want to change the logic thoguh so that the end() method triggers the callback instead of the timeout. The clue is that you have to save the callback somewhere, as written, you just triggered the callback the moment you use the done method.

Comment: Thanks, I was really close. :)